# Generating Mutiple Samples Pairs of extent n

Tags: r, statistics

Assume I have to generate 1000 Sample Pairs `(Y1,Y2)` (from a Normal Distribution with replacement). Each of the pairs should have 20 observations.

```
y1 <- rep(sample(c(1:10),10, replace = TRUE))
y2 <- rep(sample(c(1:10),10, replace = TRUE))
```

How would I now generate 1000 of these pairs, so that they are easy to access for further computations.
I had the idea of looping them a 1000 times and saving them in a dataframe, but this may get chaotic.

Is there a simpler/nicer way to do this? A package or a function that I am missing?

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `replicate`, i.e.

```
replicate(5, rep(sample(c(1:10), 10, replace = TRUE)))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    3    9    2    4    5
# [2,]    4    1   10    8    1
# [3,]    5    6    1    3    7
# [4,]    1    9    9    6    5
# [5,]    5    3    4    7    9
# [6,]    4    5    4    4    5
# [7,]    2   10    9    4    9
# [8,]    3    1   10    5    3
# [9,]    7    3   10    9   10
#[10,]   10    3   10   10    1
```